# Forward and backward looking expanding window mean calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I ran into the following challenge:

For every row in a dataframe I would like to calculate a type of scalar product of two columns with the following rules:

- for rows below and including the current row (index <= current index), calculate the scalar product of the columns `value` and `multiplier`.
- for rows above the current row (index > current index), take the sum of `value` (-> `multiplier` = 1)
- sum up both sums.

Let me illustrate this. Here is some code to create the dataframe to start off:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value': list(range(1, 11, 1))})*10

    limit = 50
    df['multiplier'] = 1+(df['value']<limit)*0.666
```

What I want to get to is the following:

```
   Index  value  multiplier  Total  
0      1     10       1.667  556.7  
1      2     20       1.667  570.0  
2      3     30       1.667  590.0  
3      4     40       1.667  616.7  
4      5     50       1.000  616.7  
5      6     60       1.000  616.7  
6      7     70       1.000  616.7  
7      8     80       1.000  616.7  
8      9     90       1.000  616.7  
9     10    100       1.000  616.7
```

For the first row, `Total` is `10 * 1.667 + scalarproduct([20, 30, 40, ..., 100} * [1]*9) = 16.67 + 540 = 556.67`. (second row: `[10, 20]*[1.667]*2 + [30, 40, ..., 100]*[1]*8`, etc.).

The weights are calculated correspondingly, and the `weighted avarage` is just the two columns divided.

My suspicion is that this would be achievable using the `pandas.api.indexers` library, but I am not sure where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear how `Weight` is calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `Total` column, you can create a function to implement the calculations, and apply it on `axis=1`. For `Index` column, you can just add 1 to the dataframe index and assign it:

```py
def funcTotal(row, df):
    mask = df.index<=row.name
    lower = (df[mask]['value']*df[mask]['multiplier']).sum()
    upper = (df[~mask]['value']).sum()
    return lower+upper

df['Total'] = df.apply(lambda x:funcTotal(x, df), axis=1)
df['Index'] = df.index+1
```

#### OUTPUT

```py
   value  multiplier   Total  Index
0     10       1.666  556.66      1
1     20       1.666  569.98      2
2     30       1.666  589.96      3
3     40       1.666  616.60      4
4     50       1.000  616.60      5
5     60       1.000  616.60      6
6     70       1.000  616.60      7
7     80       1.000  616.60      8
8     90       1.000  616.60      9
9    100       1.000  616.60     10
```

Comment: Hi there - thanks a lot! It looks like I was on a wrong path here looking for a solution with expanding windows. I will correct the down-vote as soon as I can, I tapped on the wrong button on my phone.